# How to create a flag in excel without using multiple OR statements?

Tags: excel

In excel how to flag a cell if the value in that matches a long list of items. I know If function with OR can be used but is there another way to get the job done.

What i mean is,

If i have column A which ranges from A...Z. I want to create a new column B called Flag which will be 1 if the value in the Column A is either A or C or E or F or G or H.

Like i said i can always use if(Or(A=...),1,0) but if the list of choice is in 10's or 100's i cannot call for all 100's in the OR statement. So is there an alternative?

Comment: Would you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37421100/edit) to add a specific example of what you are trying to do?  What kinds of items do you have?  Numeric or textual?  Are you using AutoFormat to highlight specific cells that have one of a number of different values?  Do you need the highlighting to update in real time, or is OK if you make changes and then run a macro to update the formatting?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have made edited the questions.

Comment: I guess when it reaches past 13, you can do it backwards but at most it's just 13. Which is still tedious but not ridiculous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list of those values in another sheet.

For example, create a new sheet, and name it "refLists" (or whatever you want)

Then in Cells A1, A2, ... etc. put your values ...

Then Name that range:

```
YourList = offset(refLists!$A$1,0,0,counta(refLists!$A:$A),1)
```

(you can call it something other than "YourList" if you want)

Then you can just do a check on that list:

```
=if(not(iserror(match("myvalue", YourList, 0))), "It's ok", "Not in list")
```

(Put your cell reference in place of "myvalue" ... and use whatever T/F conditions you need in place of "It's ok" and "Not in list")

This assumes only that your list of values in Column A is contiguous ... and has no gaps ... 
so don't leave any blank cells, else it will not work ;)

Answer (score 1):

I set up my worksheet as follows:

- Column A contains all of the letters
- Column B contains the letters to be flagged
- Column C contains the following formula

  =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$3,1,FALSE)),0,1)

If the Vlookup finds that A2 is in the flag list, then the formula returns a one. If it is absent, then the Vlookup returns an error value, ISERROR is true, and the formula returns 0.

[image]

Comment: As @Ditto suggests, the VLOOKUP can be replaced with MATCH: MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$3,0)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help.